# Understanding cv2.threshold() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, threshold

I run this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im=cv2.imread('1.jpg')
#mask=np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
imgray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(imgray,200,200,200)
countours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(im,countours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow("begueradj",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Over these 2 pictures (I display original and result pictures):

*Picture 1:*

[image]

*Picture 2:*

[image]

*Result 1 :*

[image]

*Result 2:*

[image]

**My problem:**

In *Result 1*, `threshold()` did what I expected.

But why in *Result 2* there is that green square ? According to my understanding of the `threshold()` function, only the green circle must be showed. Why is this ? What am I not understanding with this function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV treats all white pixels as foreground and the black ones as background. The green contours visualize the detected foreground.

If you wish to highlight the black circle, you'd need to invert the image beforehand. Alternatively you can use the threshold type "THRESH_BINARY_INV" (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold).

Comment: Thank you. So you mean I have 2 green boundaries because they wrap the white space in the picture ? Is it this what you mean ?

Comment: @Kabyle: Exactly. That's what I mean.

Comment: I just have been reading in the link you gave me. So if I follow the logic, can I use `THRESH_BINARY_INV` to wrap everything that is not white ? (not only black, suppose the circle is an object hat has surfaces of different colors). This is my last question. Thank you in advance. Regards

Comment: I haven't tried `THRESH_BINARY_INV`, but yes: It will "wrap" everything that is darker than the threshold (=200 in your case). To be more exact: It will return a black/white image `thresh` with a white circle, which is understood as foreground by the contour extraction method. (You might want to display the intermediate image `thresh` to get a better idea of what is happening.)

Comment: I understand (i run some examples). But why the link to your thesis on your website does not work ?

Comment: @Kabyle: Wow, I never noticed the dead link. Now it's finally fixed. Thanks!